# Find two functions that squeeze a function

Tags: calculus, limits

The question asks the following:
[image]

I'm struggling to set up some relation such that $g(x)≤f(x)≤h(x)$. Specifically, I'm struggling to find $y$-values that either the numerator or denominator of $f(x)$ lies between? Can someone please give me some guidance.

Comment: Usually we use squeeze theorem when for $f(x)$ is difficult to find the limit whereas it is simple for $h(x)$ and $g(x)$, in this case it is not difficult to see that $f(x) \to 0$. Anyway it is not difficult find suche $h(x)$ and $g(x)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINT**

For example

$$g(x)=\frac{|x|}{x^4+4x^2+8}\to 0$$

$$h(x)=\frac{|x|}{x^4+4x^2+6} \to 0$$

or

$$g(x)=\frac{|x|}{x^2+4x^2+7}=\frac{|x|}{5x^2+7}\to 0$$

$$h(x)=\frac{|x|}{x^4+4x^4+7}=\frac{|x|}{5x^4+7} \to 0$$